# How do I link and built a dynamic link library correctly?

Tags: c++, opengl, build-process, ctypes

I am in linux.  My Makefile file is this

```
main2: main.cpp
g++ -c $(LIBS) $(CFLAGS) -fPIC main.cpp
g++ -shared main.o -o main.so
```

Where,

```
SDL_CFLAGS := $(shell sdl-config --cflags)
SDL_LDFLAGS := $(shell sdl-config --libs)
CC = gcc
COPTS = -g -Wall
CFLAGS = $(SDL_CFLAGS)
LIBS = -lstdc++ -lSDL $(SDL_LDFLAGS) -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lGL -lGLU
```

which runs

```
g++ -c -lstdc++ -lSDL -L/usr/lib -lSDL -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lGL -lGLU -I/usr/include/SDL -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_REENTRANT -fPIC main.cpp

g++ -shared main.o -o main.so
```

Now, this works without error.  main.o and main.so files are produced.

However, when I try to link main.os with python ctypes

```
from ctypes import * import os
libtest = cdll.LoadLibrary(os.getcwd()+ '/main.so') libtest.main_loop()
libtest.main_loop()
```

I get this error

```
>>> libtest = cdll.LoadLibrary(os.getcwd() + '/main.so')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 431, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 353, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: /home/atomos/DF/open_gl_client/ctypes_client/main.so: undefined symbol: glEnd
```

I am not sure if I am creating the linked library correctly.  How do I create a linked library that I can load?

Do I have to create a .o and .os file for every library I import from main.cpp or is that taken care of automatically?

I do not understand what the compiler or linker is doing, however it works for a simple example with no imports, but for cpp files which import opengl libraries, it gives that error.

---- Update----
ldd against main.so yields

```
ldd main.so
        linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb7755000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0xaf625000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libm.so.6 (0xaf5ff000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0xaf4a4000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xaf485000)
        /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb7756000)
```

---- Update ----

I ran g++ without -shared flag in the second compilation step and received this error

```
 g++ main.o -o main.so
main.o: In function `Texture_map_list::add_texture(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)':
main.cpp:(.text+0xf0fe): undefined reference to `glGenTextures'
main.cpp:(.text+0xf2ba): undefined reference to `glBindTexture'
main.cpp:(.text+0xf2d7): undefined reference to `glTexParameterf'
main.cpp:(.text+0xf2f4): undefined reference to `glTexParameterf'
main.cpp:(.text+0xf310): undefined reference to `glTexParameteri'
main.cpp:(.text+0xf32c): undefined reference to `glTexParameteri'
main.cpp:(.text+0xf365): undefined reference to `gluBuild2DMipmaps'
main.o: In function `init()':
main.cpp:(.text+0xf457): undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
main.cpp:(.text+0xf46d): undefined reference to `SDL_WM_SetCaption'
main.cpp:(.text+0xf472): undefined reference to `SDL_GetVideoInfo'
main.cpp:(.text+0xf480): undefined reference to `SDL_GetError'
main.cpp:(.text+0xf497): undefined reference to `SDL_Quit'
main.cpp:(.text+0xf4e2): undefined reference to `SDL_GL_SetAttribute'
main.cpp:(.text+0xf505): undefined reference to `SDL_SetVideoMode'
main.cpp:(.text+0xf513): undefined reference to `SDL_GetError'
main.cpp:(.text+0xf52a): undefined reference to `SDL_Quit'
main.cpp:(.text+0xf559): undefined reference to `glClearColor'
main.cpp:(.text+0xf565): undefined reference to `glEnable'
main.cpp:(.text+0xf571): undefined reference to `glMatrixMode'
main.cpp:(.text+0xf576): undefined reference to `glLoadIdentity'
main.cpp:(.text+0xf5a2): undefined reference to `gluPerspective'
main.o: In function `process_keypresses()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x10678): undefined reference to `SDL_PollEvent'
main.cpp:(.text+0x109a1): undefined reference to `SDL_PollEvent'
main.o: In function `main_loop':
main.cpp:(.text+0x10d76): undefined reference to `SDL_GetKeyState'
main.cpp:(.text+0x10d9f): undefined reference to `SDL_Quit'
main.o: In function `render()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x10e00): undefined reference to `SDL_GetMouseState'
main.cpp:(.text+0x10e90): undefined reference to `SDL_GetMouseState'
main.cpp:(.text+0x10f94): undefined reference to `glClear'
main.cpp:(.text+0x10fa0): undefined reference to `glMatrixMode'
main.cpp:(.text+0x10fa5): undefined reference to `glLoadIdentity'
main.cpp:(.text+0x11081): undefined reference to `gluLookAt'
main.cpp:(.text+0x11120): undefined reference to `glTranslatef'
main.cpp:(.text+0x1114d): undefined reference to `glRotatef'
main.cpp:(.text+0x1117a): undefined reference to `glRotatef'
main.cpp:(.text+0x1119e): undefined reference to `SDL_GL_SwapBuffers'
main.o: In function `draw_plane(float, float, float)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x111d8): undefined reference to `glColor3f'
main.cpp:(.text+0x111e4): undefined reference to `glBegin'
main.cpp:(.text+0x1120b): undefined reference to `glVertex3f'
```

....

Comment: "build file" - I think you mean *Makefile*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, note that this is easier to debug if you don't build a shared library. You are building with -shared so the linker errors don't happen until you dynamically load the library in Python. Turn off -shared while you are debugging, and you will see the errors on the command-line when you try to link:

```
g++ main.o -o main
main.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x1d): undefined reference to `glBegin'
main.cpp:(.text+0x22): undefined reference to `glEnd'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Now the problem is that you are passing linker arguments to the compiler. I see that you have nicely separated `CFLAGS` and `LIBS` in the Makefile. Good. But you are passing both `$(LIBS)` and `$(CFLAGS)` on the first line, to build main.o. The `LIBS` will be ignored on that line, because they are link flags.

On the second line, where you are actually building the final executable, you do not pass `$(LIBS)`, so the program is not linked with libGL or any other libraries.

Therefore, simply fix your makefile thusly:

```
main2: main.cpp
    g++ -c $(CFLAGS) -fPIC main.cpp
    g++ -shared main.o $(LIBS) -o main.so
```

**Edit**: I have since realised that in GCC, you must [always put the libraries after the object files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640642/gcc-link-order-changed/8640681), so I have changed the last line of the makefile accordingly.

Comment: Great to hear. Can you tick the 'accepted answer' checkbox to flag this as solved? Thanks.

Comment: I hit the accepted answer box and upvoted.  Sorry, that I forgot to do that.

Comment: @HaltingState Heh, no worries. I like that you came back more than a year later. I got a badge out of it ("Enlightened") because you ticked it after so many people voted it up :) Also note that I have just edited the answer because I have since discovered that you need to put libs after .o files.

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

You are passing the link flags to object compilation step.

Here is what you need:

```
g++ -c -I/usr/include/SDL -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_REENTRANT main.cpp
g++ -lstdc++ -lSDL -L/usr/lib -lSDL -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lGL -lGLU -fPIC main.o -o main
```

Plus you probably don't want to create so file, but a normal executable.

Comment: Well, he does want to create a so file, since he's importing it into Python.