# Difference in shared object linking between Natty Narwhal and Oneiric Ocelot

Tags: c++, ubuntu, g++, ubuntu-11.10

I am writing a simple proof of concept C++ application (available at https://github.com/paulspencerwilliams/CPlusPlusSocialPlayground) compiled using twitcurl using the exact instructions at http://code.google.com/p/twitcurl/wiki/WikiHowToUseTwitcurlLibrary . I can compile and install twitcurl without problem, and I can compile and execute my application on Natty Narwhal. However, compiling my app (via the Makefile) on Oneiric Ocelot gives me the following linking problem:

```
g++ -ltwitcurl twitterClient.cpp -o twitterClient
/tmp/ccbxmSF3.o: In function `main':
twitterClient.cpp:(.text+0x1f7): undefined reference to `twitCurl::twitCurl()'
twitterClient.cpp:(.text+0x22e): undefined reference to `twitCurl::setTwitterUsername(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)'
twitterClient.cpp:(.text+0x247): undefined reference to `twitCurl::setTwitterPassword(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)'
twitterClient.cpp:(.text+0x280): undefined reference to `twitCurl::getOAuth()'
twitterClient.cpp:(.text+0x292): undefined reference to `oAuth::setConsumerKey(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
twitterClient.cpp:(.text+0x2e9): undefined reference to `twitCurl::getOAuth()'
twitterClient.cpp:(.text+0x2fb): undefined reference to `oAuth::setConsumerSecret(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
twitterClient.cpp:(.text+0x50c): undefined reference to `twitCurl::getOAuth()'
twitterClient.cpp:(.text+0x51e): undefined reference to `oAuth::setOAuthTokenKey(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
twitterClient.cpp:(.text+0x52d): undefined reference to `twitCurl::getOAuth()'
twitterClient.cpp:(.text+0x53f): undefined reference to `oAuth::setOAuthTokenSecret(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
twitterClient.cpp:(.text+0x56c): undefined reference to `twitCurl::oAuthRequestToken(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)'
twitterClient.cpp:(.text+0x664): undefined reference to `twitCurl::getOAuth()'
twitterClient.cpp:(.text+0x676): undefined reference to `oAuth::setOAuthPin(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
twitterClient.cpp:(.text+0x691): undefined reference to `twitCurl::oAuthHandlePIN(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
twitterClient.cpp:(.text+0x6a0): undefined reference to `twitCurl::oAuthAccessToken()'
twitterClient.cpp:(.text+0x6af): undefined reference to `twitCurl::getOAuth()'
twitterClient.cpp:(.text+0x6c1): undefined reference to `oAuth::getOAuthTokenKey(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)'
twitterClient.cpp:(.text+0x6d0): undefined reference to `twitCurl::getOAuth()'
twitterClient.cpp:(.text+0x6e2): undefined reference to `oAuth::getOAuthTokenSecret(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)'
twitterClient.cpp:(.text+0x88e): undefined reference to `twitCurl::statusUpdate(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)'
twitterClient.cpp:(.text+0x8ab): undefined reference to `twitCurl::getLastWebResponse(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)'
twitterClient.cpp:(.text+0x8e7): undefined reference to `twitCurl::getLastCurlError(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)'
twitterClient.cpp:(.text+0x97e): undefined reference to `twitCurl::timelineUserGet(bool, bool, unsigned int, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, bool)'
twitterClient.cpp:(.text+0x9bb): undefined reference to `twitCurl::getLastWebResponse(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)'
twitterClient.cpp:(.text+0x9f7): undefined reference to `twitCurl::getLastCurlError(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)'
twitterClient.cpp:(.text+0xa86): undefined reference to `twitCurl::~twitCurl()'
twitterClient.cpp:(.text+0xc64): undefined reference to `twitCurl::~twitCurl()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Any ideas what the difference in compiling on these two platforms is? For exact comparison, I've tried this on Ubuntu 64 bit images on AWS and get the same symptoms.

Edit: I've changed the order of parameters in my Makefile, and it no seems to get past the first issue. However, I'm now presented with the following error when compiling:

```
g++ twitterClient.cpp -o twitterClient -ltwitcurl
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../lib/libtwitcurl.so: undefined reference to `curl_easy_getinfo'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../lib/libtwitcurl.so: undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../lib/libtwitcurl.so: undefined reference to `curl_easy_init'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../lib/libtwitcurl.so: undefined reference to `curl_slist_append'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../lib/libtwitcurl.so: undefined reference to `curl_slist_free_all'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../lib/libtwitcurl.so: undefined reference to `curl_easy_perform'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../lib/libtwitcurl.so: undefined reference to `curl_easy_cleanup'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Comment: This sounds like a linker problem. Probably you must specify other libraries, or explicitly specify the library with -L option.
Try also to specify the libraries as last argument
`gcc test.cpp -o test -ltwitcurl`
otherwise try to check the architectures of the libraries you're trying to link. Probably they are in /usr/lib/libtwitcurl or similar.
If they are 32 bit then you must specify -m32 to gcc I think

Comment: possible duplicate of [GCC link order changed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640642/gcc-link-order-changed)

Comment: It is a linking problem, and I've changed the ordering of arguments, but this leads to a secondary issue. I've edited my original post in accordance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The newer `gcc` version of Oneiric requires the link argument to be set after the source files:

```
g++ twitterClient.cpp -o twitterClient -ltwitcurl
```

Comment: Cheers! I've changed the command line ordering but get the second error now, in the edited original post.

Comment: The Makefile distributed with twitcurl has similar problems to mine. I changed the g++ command line around to apply -lcurl at the end and now the application compiles and runs on Oneiric Ocelot.