# Does the order in which libraries appear on the gcc command line matter?

Tags: gcc, linker, libraries

I always thought that libraries had to be listed *after* any object files that depended on them, but given this simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    double res;

    res = acos(2);
    printf("res = %f\n", res);
    return 0;
}
```

If I build it *without* linking in `libm`, it fails as expected:

```
$ gcc -o mathtest mathtest.c 
/tmp/cc9x6HZA.o: In function `main':
mathtest.c:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to `acos'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But I can list `-lm` either before or after the source file and it links successfully:

```
gcc -o mathtest -lm mathtest.c
gcc -o mathtest mathtest.c -lm
```

And I get the same behavior if I compile the source to an object file first and then link it as above.

Did this  behavior change at some point? Or was it always like this, and I was just confused?

Comment: This question seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640642/gcc-link-order-changed?rq=1
See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8640681/1733277

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the order of '-l' option in gcc matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11893996/608639) and [Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45135/608639)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confirm the unexpected link-order behaviour that you observe with gcc 5.1 and
also that I have the traditional behaviour with gcc 4.9.2. I would infer that this
novelty comes in with gcc 5.x, and that your toolchain is gcc 5.x. Possibly it
is a distro-specific anomaly of the toolchain build. My toolchain is as per ubuntu 14.04.

The novel behaviour only affects *dynamic* libraries. I can see what is causing it
if I link in verbose mode (`-v`) with gcc 4.9.2 and also with gcc 5.1, placing `-lm` before it is needed,
and examine the differences in the verbose output.

From gcc 4.9.2 I have (with artifical line-wrapping):

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/collect2 -plugin /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/liblto_plugin.so 
-plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccsHNLNB.res 
-plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc 
-plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s --sysroot=/ --build-id 
--eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu --as-needed -dynamic-linker 
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -z relro -o mathtest 
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o 
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o 
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9 
-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu
-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu 
-L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib 
-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../.. -lm mathtest.o -lgcc --as-needed 
-lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed 
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/crtend.o 
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
```

And from gcc 5.1 I have:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/collect2 -plugin /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/liblto_plugin.so 
-plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/cc5hI8vd.res 
-plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc 
-plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s --sysroot=/ --build-id 
--eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu -dynamic-linker 
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -z relro -o mathtest 
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o 
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o 
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5 
-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu 
-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu 
-L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib 
-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../.. -lm mathtest.o -lgcc --as-needed 
-lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed 
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/crtend.o 
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
```

The relevant difference is that the gcc 4.9.2 linkage passes the option `--as-needed`
in 4 places whereas the gcc 5.1 linkage passes it in only 3. gcc 4.9.2 passes `--as-needed`
for the first time at the the 5th quoted "line":

```
--eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu --as-needed -dynamic-linker
```

gcc 5.1 does not pass it there. Thereafter, both linkages pass this option at
the same 3 places, starting as the 13th "line":

```
-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../.. -lm mathtest.o -lgcc --as-needed
```

This means that for gcc 4.9.2, the library option `-lm` on "line" 13 falls within the
scope of the first `--as-needed`. For gcc 5.1 it does not. The effect of this option
is to inform the linker that the dynamic library `libm` (or any dynamic library that
is encountered in the option's scope)  shall be linked only *if it is encountered
at a point in the linkage at which it can satisfy some unresolved symbols*. In the
absence of this option, at a given point in the linkage, a dynamic library is by
default deemed to be needed for the linkage regardless of whether there are yet any
unresolved symbols that it can satisfy. See [the documentation of `--as-needed`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#Options)

Thus the gcc 4.9.2 linkage will not link `libm`, although it appears on the
commandline, because at the point where it appears - before `mathtest.o` - `--as-needed` is
in force and there are as yet no unresolved references that `libm` satisfies. The gcc 5.1
linkage *will* link `libm` because it appears on the commandline at a point where `--as-needed`
is not in force.