# Linking in a static library failes, but linking a shared library succeeds

Tags: c++, linux, g++, ld

I can build my application against the shared library but I'm getting the unresolved symbol errors when linking it against the static version of the same library:

I can build my application this way:

```
g++ -lutils application.cpp -o application.exe
```

The above command links in the shared version of an utils library.

I'm trying link against the static version of the library like this:

```
g++ -l:utils.a application.cpp -o application.exe
```

Both times I'm using

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=path/to/utils:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

to inform g++ where utils.a is placed.

The unresolved symbol reported by ld is present in the output of the nm:

```
nm --defined-only path/to/utils.a
```

and is marked with the "T" (meaning that it is from the code section).

I'm trying to figure out what can be the reason of the problem.

Is it correct to use LD_LIBRARY_PATH to specify where to search for utils.a?

What is the exact command to verify that a static library defines (resolves) the symbol? Is the command

```
nm --defined-only path/to/utils.a
```

enough or should I use any additional options like

```
nm --defined-only --demangle path/to/utils.a
```

e.g.?

Comment: No, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not used in the linking process. Do you mean `LIBRARY_PATH`? The library path is usually specified with the `-L` option to `gcc`. Can you please copy-paste the error message from gcc verbatim? Also check that it actually found the library, because `-lutils` would find a file named `libutils.so` or `libutils.a`, not `utils.a`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45135/608639), [Does the order in which libraries appear on the gcc command line matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31867741/608639), etc.

Comment: Also, I believe `-l:utils.a` is incorrect. When using filename spec you need to use actual filename, like `-l:libutils.a`. Also see the [`ld(1)` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld).

Comment: Put `-lutils` after source and object files. Read up how linkers process the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Just option -static should be enough for compiler. In case only one library has to be static, then -static- and lib name is short name not file name.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it correct to use LD_LIBRARY_PATH to specify where to search for utils.a?

1. As mentioned by @user10605163, LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not to find path to static library at compile and link time. It is an environment variable used in *some* Linux distribution to search shared libraries during run time. Please find more documentation [here](http://tldp.org//HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html) It is useful for build and test environment but not a recommended way of linking in production systems.

> What is the exact command to verify that a static library defines (resolves) the symbol? Is the command nm --defined-only path/to/utils.a

2. Yes, that is correct. However based on the information provided this error is not likely an error with symbols not present in utils(as it worked with shared library), but with the linking.

Refer [GNU documentation GCC link options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html)
Excerpt:

> -l library : Search the library named library when linking. The linker searches a standard list of directories for the library. The directories searched include several standard system directories plus any that you specify with -L.

Also, with -l link option you need to provide the library name (without 'lib' and extension) or full file name. 
-lutils or -llibutils.a
You can also provide direct full path here only, if required.